# Text becomes "Red" color; Can't find the code that makes it "Red"

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, layout

I have a simple php page which outputs a table (which has been created dynamically).

The text on the page is all red marked, unless you specifically put a `font color` element and force it to become black.

I use FF and have Firebug installed, so I wonder if you guys have any tips on how to troubleshoot why this text isn't black?

I have tried:

1- Setting the body text color to 000 both with css and html... Didn't work!
2- Checking all classes.

Any tips???

All I have figured out is that when I DONT include my css files, the text becomes black standard. And I have looked at the css files without finding anything suspicious.

How should I troubleshoot?

Isn't there any way to check which styles if any, a text has applied to it somehow?

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML to make sure there are no inline styles or deprecated `fgcolor="red"` attributes?

Comment: I'd say grep/search your CSS for 'red', '#F00', or '#FF0000'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the element in Firebug it should tell you all the styles attached to that element (Including the inherited ones)

Like in the screen shot in the page below.

http://getfirebug.com/css

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, I forgot the cache of the browser!

I have used 3 different browsers, and none of them updated the cache when I hit F5 several times, so all 3 where showing the old color.

Sorry guys, and thanks!

Comment: Try CTRL-F5 or CTRL-SHIFT-R to refresh the page and cache

Answer (score 0):

You could also use chromes development by just simply  right clicking the text and inspecting element.  Its not as developed as firebug, however, its very easy to use.